# JS: how to handle error from nested then() in outer catch block?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-promise, catch-block

I am following a tutorial about handling errors of fetch() but now it turns to be learning handling errors. This is the code I wrote. I wish to handle all errors inside the outer catch:

```
        fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        name: this.enteredName,
        rating: this.chosenRating
      }
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        //...
      } else {
        response.json().then(json => {
          const msg = 'Custom error handling: could not save data' +
            ', error code: ' + response.status + ', error: ' + json.error;
          throw new Error(msg);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log('catch1:');
          throw e;
        });
      }
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('catch2:');
        this.error = err.message;
      });
```

The problem with this code is that the outer catch cannot catch the error from inner then block, even through I rethrow it in inner catch block. What would be a clean and elegant way to achieve this? Please dont change response.ok because I wish to learn the solution for this exact situation.

Comment: Return the promise.

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.enteredName,
    rating: this.chosenRating
  })
}).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    //...
  } else {
    return response.json().then(json => {
      const msg = 'Custom error handling: could not save data' +
        ', error code: ' + response.status + ', error: ' + json.error;
      throw new Error(msg);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('catch1:');
      return Promise.reject(e); // Use return Promise.reject() to propagate the error
    });
  }
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('catch2:');
  this.error = err.message;
});
```

By using `return Promise.reject(e);` in the inner catch block, you ensure that the rejected promise is propagated down the chain, allowing the outer `catch` block to handle the error. This way, you don't need to rethrow the error in the outer catch block, and it will be caught by the outer catch block as intended.

Comment: Using `throw e` instead of `return Promise.reject(e)` is totally fine

Comment: I wonder why adding a `return` before `response.json()` make the outer catch able to catch the error? what difference does it make?

Comment: @Bergi `threw e` also works. I wonder why adding a `return` before `response.json()` make the outer catch able to catch the error? what difference does it make?

Comment: @fall Because if you don't `return` anything from the callback, the `then` method cannot know to reject the promise returned by the `.then()` call